# Massive Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a project which it's environment initialized in eclipse and has been built in eclipse. There were no lack of performance in loading and running of project.
We decided to migrate or environment on a maven base platform.
Due to number of sub modules of project(around 400 sub modules), loading of project become a nightmare.
So what is the solution in this kind of situation?

Comment: Avoid having so many modules? Work on one module at a time?

Comment: You mean in my IDE or in my project structure?

Comment: I mean avoid having so many modules in your Maven project, and working on one module at a time in the IDE.

Comment: How can I avoid having these modules in my project if it is my business requirement?

Comment: I have never heard a customer ask: "I want my product to allow selling cars online. I'd like the background to be blue. Oh, and most importantly: it must have at least 400 Maven modules". The choice of how you split the project into modules is a purely technical and organisational one, that has nothing to do with business requirements. You created a monster of a system, not the customer.

Comment: Of course it is not what customers ask. As I know, analyze of business defines aspect of a project and those aspects reflect on modules which you design. For sure technical and organisational issues are effective as well as analyze of business. Am i totally wrong here?

Comment: I don't know anything about your project, but I'm willing to bet that many, many jars produced by all those modules are always deployed together as a single application. If that's the case, you could just group them into a single module. Java packages inside a module are there to arrange classes per functionality and technical layers. No need to split everything into modules.

Comment: I have problem with this approach. If you think that modules should be mirror of our deployment scenario, how i should handle abstraction  of our app layers? I mean there is at least one data access layer, one business layer and one presentation layer and of course there are a lot more layers in our app.

Comment: packages are sufficient. And I doubt you have 400 layers in your app. Why would you have a lot more layers? functional domains, maybe (but once again, thereare packages for that), but layers? Anyway, if you think your separation into a multitude of modules makes sense, go for it, but don't complain that it's a nightmare to maintain and that it takes ages for Eclipse to parse all those files, digure out the dependencies and build everything.

Comment: The real situation is that our app is contained of about 20 components. Some components have their own abstraction layers, which are contained of about 4 or 5 modules each, and some modules are customer customized which because of number of our customers there is about 20 modules in these kind of component which in deployment one of them will be deployed.
Maybe you are right and our approach is hideous and we created a monster but I want to make the monster as smaller as I can.
Any way thanks for your help. That would be great If you introduce any document about different approach in the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your 400-module-project into smaller projects following one of the following approaches - depending on the organisation of your development environment:

1) Divide by business domains aspects

Is there functionality that can be seen as self-contained? E.g. user/access control,  master data management, accounting, reporting, etc. If there is such those are good candidates for separate projects.

Example:

```
+- your-application
   +- commons
      +- ... functionality/tools used by all others ...
   +- access-control
      +- ... access control modules ...
   +- master-data
      +- ... master data modules ...
   +- accounting
      +- ... accounting modules ...
   +- reporting
      +- ... reporting modules ...
   +- ...
      + ...
```

2) Divide by technical aspects

Your *"one data access layer, one business layer and one presentation layer"* are good candidates for separate projects.

Example:

```
+- your-application
   +- commons
     +- ... functionality/tools used by all others ...
   +- data-access
      +- ... your data access modules ...
   +- business
      +- ... your business layer modules ...
   +- presentation
      +- ... your presentation layer modules ...
```

3) A combination of the two above

Example:

```
+- your-application
   +- commons
      +- ... functionality/tools used by all others ...
   +- access-control
      +- data-access
      +- business
      +- presentation
      +- integration-tests
   +- master-data
      +- data-access
      +- business
      +- presentation
      +- integration-tests
      +- ...
   +- accounting
      +- data-access
      +- business
      +- presentation
      +- integration-tests
      +- ...
   +- reporting
      +- data-access
      +- business
      +- presentation
      +- integration-tests
      +- ...
   +- ...
      + ...
```

Comment: Is there any documentation, any where about these approaches?

Comment: @Ali.Valizadeh Nothing specific that I'm aware of. I know this from years and years of experience in software design. Search for appropriate presentations/tutorials/books/articles with the terms "modular software design". Don't cling to Maven too much at first. Maven itself is "just" a tool that supports bringing a modular design to life - though it does this extremly well.