# Recommended project structure for scalable multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, design-patterns, multi-module

I'm working on application that has to communicate like Restful client with Endpoint1, Endpoint2,...EndpointN calling methods let's say getAaa and getBbb. Every Endpoint has same methods and return the same context information but using own parameter list for calls and returning own response object structure.
Till now I worked on prototype having only webapp project and 1 Endpoint like separate package in web project and it was quite simple to call methods and consume response or exceptions. Now I need to add Endpoint2, then expand further and I stuck to project design questions - how to have flexible structure and how to have unified response from all Endpoints calling methods in my ejb. Please point me to the right direction how to design Maven project structure  and how to wire calls from ejb to different Endpoint using different parameter list and how to unify different response and catch exceptions to MyObject or MyExObject?

P.S.: I have full control of Endpoint Restful client code

[image]

Comment: You can create a new project which just serves responses like object/exception have enp1/2/3 add this new project as it dependency

Comment: Can you explain why you're considering a multi-module project?

Comment: i'm pretty new with Maven but my feeling is that for large and scalable project I need to create multimodule Maven project with parent-pom, create webapp-pom and let's say apis-pom projects. The last one for managing end developing separate pom project for every Endpoint. But I'm NOT SURE. If I'm correct then remains second part of my question - what is the recommended way to call webapp.ejb.ApiResponse<MyObject> =  getAaaa(My param1 list, Endpoint1) when response will be endpoint1.ApiResponce<Object> when ApiResponse<MyObject>  and ApiResponse<Object>  are from different packages

Comment: Do the suggestions [in this answer to _Massive Maven Project_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682935/1744774) or in [this answer to _Java - Maven - Reusing Entity layer at both client and server side projects_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631677/1744774) help you?